# how to show quick access bar in spreadjs - grapecity

Tags: spreadjs

How can I enable quick access bar in spreadjs ? Found js and css for .quick-access-bar class but not found any html for it. Need to enable any options in js?

Answer (score 1):

I am a member of GrapeCity’s Technical Engagement team for SpreadJS. At this time, we do not have a quick access bar in SpreadJS’s runtime library. However, we do offer a source code license for the SpreadJS Designer that does include the code for the quick access bar. Feel free to reach out to our team with any other questions!
Best, 
Mackenzie Albitz